# Rails linking url paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I did not generate the complete user model and i do not know how i can link to the user profile. I have tried:

```
<%= link_to u.username, user_show_path(u) %>
```

However it only shows an error, if it's any difference I am also using the devise gem

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways link_to can be used

```
  link_to u.username, user_path(u)
  link_to u.username, u
  link_to u.username, :controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => u
```

all should work, the issue could be that you are using user_show_path

Comment: Thnks, i used the last one then got a routing issue, ill try and resolve it

Comment: yes, make sure you have a show method in your users controller.

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, used the link

```
link_to u.username, :controller => "users", :action => "show", :id => u
```

and then wrote a simple route,

```
match "/user/:id" => "users#show"
```